# how Do i get the time only, no date?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

Hello I am using pandas to_datetime to convert data column in a dataframe
But I only want the time part only the (Hours and minutes) i do not want the date in this case.

This is my code:

```
converted_air_time = pd.to_datetime(flight_data["AirTime"], unit = "s")
print converted_air_time
Output: 0        1970-01-01 00:02:12
```

I only want the 00:02:12 section

if anyone knows please assist thanks

Comment: Try this: `pd.to_datetime(flight_data["AirTime"], unit = "s").dt.time`

Answer (score 0):

```
print converted_air_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```